# Sorting python bubble both

Tags: python, sorting

I'm writing a two way bubble sort function called bubble_both. On each pass through the list the direction changes. So after the first pass the maximum value is in its correct place and after the second pass the minimum value is in its correct place, and so on.

The sort finishes as soon as there are no swaps in a pass.

The function should print the list each time through a pass and the number of comparisons made and the number of swaps made on that pass as in the following example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjLgq.png)

Below is what I have tried but it seems to have some errors:

```
def bubble_both(a_list):
   exchanges = True
   pass_num = len(a_list) - 1
   while pass_num > 0 and exchanges:
       exchanges = False
       for i in range(pass_num):
           if a_list[i] > a_list[i + 1]:
               exchanges = True
               a_list[i], a_list[i + 1] = a_list[i + 1], a_list[i]
       pass_num = pass_num - 1
```

Comment: FWIW, a bidirectional bubble sort is sometimes called a [cocktail shaker sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort); Wikipedia mentions several other names. However, I don't see any bidirectionality in the code you posted.

Comment: I suggest that you work through your algorithm manually, on paper, with a small list of, say, 5 elements and see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your code works well, in the sense that it sorts the data correctly. But it looks like a straightforward unidirectional sort to me. The problem statement calls for the `bubble_both()` function to print out progress reports as it goes along. There is no `print()` call in the code, so you see no progress reports. But after calling the function, the variable `a_list` is in fact sorted. I added a `print()` call as the first line of the function and this is what I got:

```
>>> a_list
[54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
>>> bubble_both(a_list)
[54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
[26, 54, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
[26, 54, 17, 93, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
[26, 54, 17, 77, 93, 31, 44, 55, 20]
[26, 54, 17, 77, 31, 93, 44, 55, 20]
[26, 54, 17, 77, 31, 44, 93, 55, 20]
[26, 54, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 93, 20]
[26, 54, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20, 93]
[26, 17, 54, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20, 93]
[26, 17, 54, 31, 77, 44, 55, 20, 93]
[26, 17, 54, 31, 44, 77, 55, 20, 93]
[26, 17, 54, 31, 44, 55, 77, 20, 93]
[26, 17, 54, 31, 44, 55, 20, 77, 93]
[17, 26, 54, 31, 44, 55, 20, 77, 93]
[17, 26, 31, 54, 44, 55, 20, 77, 93]
[17, 26, 31, 44, 54, 55, 20, 77, 93]
[17, 26, 31, 44, 54, 20, 55, 77, 93]
[17, 26, 31, 44, 20, 54, 55, 77, 93]
[17, 26, 31, 20, 44, 54, 55, 77, 93]
[17, 26, 20, 31, 44, 54, 55, 77, 93]
[17, 20, 26, 31, 44, 54, 55, 77, 93]
```

The code doesn't count the exchanges as the problem statement. It just uses a true/false flag. So I didn't attempt to print that out.